# Exceptions in the weblogic server - Illegal attempt to call EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic8.x

I get the following exception in the Weblogic server,from the logs, it is definitely something internal to the weblogic, but, not sure which part of the application the weblogic is trying to archive, do you know why it is happening?

```
<Nov 4, 2015 10:32:07 AM CST> <Info> <EJB> <BEA-010213> <Message-Driven EJB: WLIArchiverSchedulerMDB's transaction was rolledback. The transaction details are: Xid=BEA1-0482AE5EBACD7EBCD75C(5835637),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=0,seconds left=60,XAServerResourceInfo[JMS_cgJMSStore]=(ServerResourceInfo[JMS_cgJMSStore]=(state=rolledback,assigned=msolvint101-prd01-z),xar=JMS_cgJMSStore,re-Registered = false),XAServerResourceInfo[cgPool]=(ServerResourceInfo[cgPool]=(state=rolledback,assigned=msolvint101-prd01-z),xar=cgPool,re-Registered = false),SCInfo[m6intdomain+msolvint101-prd01-z]=(state=rolledback),properties=({ISOLATION LEVEL=2}),local properties=({weblogic.jdbc.jta.cgPool=weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.TxInfo@1ff65e5}),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=msolvint101-prd01-z+msolvint101-prd01-z.tds.local:7001+m6intdomain+t3+, XAResources={JMS_FileStore, JMS_pluginStore, cgPool, NetExpert Pool, MSLVPool, JMS_cgJMSStore, MSLVwliPool, bpmArchPool},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=msolvint101-prd01-z+msolvint101-prd01-z.tds.local:7001+m6intdomain+t3+).>
<Nov 4, 2015 10:32:07 AM CST> <Warning> <EJB> <BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010158]Illegal attempt to call EJBContext.setRollbackOnly() from an EJB that was not participating in a transaction..
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010158]Illegal attempt to call EJBContext.setRollbackOnly() from an EJB that was not participating in a transaction.
        at weblogic.ejb20.internal.BaseEJBContext.setRollbackOnly(BaseEJBContext.java:348)
        at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MessageDrivenEJBContextImpl.setRollbackOnly(MessageDrivenEJBContextImpl.java:56)
        at com.bea.wli.management.archiving.WLIArchiverSchedulerMDB.onMessage(WLIArchiverSchedulerMDB.java:164)
        at com.bea.wli.management.archiving.WLIArchiverSchedulerMDB.onMessage(WLIArchiverSchedulerMDB.java:75)
        at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:400)
        at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:333)
        at weblogic.ejb20.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:298)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:2686)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:2598)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MDB [transaction attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html) is set to Required and not to NotSupported

Comment: we dont use mdbs in our application, if you take a look at the logs, those are some internal weblogic errors, and we are clueless as to what is causing these exceptions.

Comment: You do not use Weblogic messaging (JMS) either?

Comment: we use jms, but, they are handled by Java consumers & producers but not MDBs.

Comment: are you using WebLogic Integration - Business Connect?

Comment: We use Weblogic Integration and i'm not sure what 'business connect' is.

Comment: I vaguely remember to bump into a similar problem with the Archive Schedule option in WL business connect.